# Google Apps Script to remove extra spaces from a Google Document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

Google Documents don't allow extra spaces to be removed using search and replace like other text editors. Can anyone help with a Google Apps Script that searches a Document for all instances of two or more spaces and replaces them with single spaces?

Comment: Please show your attempt at doing this yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. We will help you if you try and run into problems, but will not write it for you.

Comment: I've discovered that, like Pages, I can select and copy the item I want replaced in Docs and then use the 'Find and replace' menu item and paste what I've copied into the search field to achieve what I'm after manually, but I'm keen to add a custom menu item using a Google Apps Script if possible. Will have a go at a script when I get a chance.

Comment: In the future, please post with code when the code is relevant.

Answer (score 6):

Such a replacement can be done with the following one-line function:

```
function spaces() {  
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().replaceText(" +", " ");
}
```

Reference: [replaceText method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern-replacement).

Comment: Thanks @sandwich. Added to my docs custom menu and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I got TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getBody')

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).